# C# Error: "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I'm using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5mxkytfWk) to try and populate results from a `DataGridView`, and am receiving the above error.  The below code pertains to this error - I pass values into a stored procedure, then the final `SELECT` returns the values in the table in the `DataGridView`.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;data source=SERV;" + "persist security info=False;initial catalog=DB";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
        SqlCommand enter = new SqlCommand("sp_Proc", con);

        // Stored Procedure
        enter.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        enter.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vvalue", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = Convert.ToString(txt1.Text);
        enter.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dvalue", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txt2.Text);
        enter.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // DataGrid returns the SELECT

        SqlDataAdapter sadapt = new SqlDataAdapter(select);
        sadapt.SelectCommand = select;
        DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
        sadapt.Fill(dtab); // generates the error
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = dtab;
        dGrid.DataSource = b;
        sadapt.Update(dtab);

        con.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You did not pass `connection` object on the `command`. Try this instead,

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", con);
```

Comment: Thanks; your set of eyes caught my mistake.

Comment: @JohnWoo: It helped me also..!! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing connection object to your **enter** command but didnt pass the connection object to your **select** command

```
  SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
  SqlCommand enter = new SqlCommand("sp_Proc", con);
```

**Use this**

```
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table",con);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StockAnalysis2") // connection missing in sqlcommand

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StockAnalysis2",Connection())// pass connection
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.